# Is there a way to represent temporal data in RDFs?

Tags: semantics, rdf, semantic-web, temporal

I have bunch of temporal data which I want to convert to RDF format. Is there any accepted way of doing so?

---

Example of tabulated data which should be somehow converted into RDF format:

```
| Name   | Date      | Salary     |
-----------------------------------
| John   | Jan 2012  |      3,244 |
| John   | Feb 2012  |      4,012 |
| John   | Mar 2012  |      3,112 |
```

---

Found one way to do it, however it is rather cubersome and introduce very large vocabularies. Assuming syntax (Subject, Predicate, Object)

```
(JohnJan2012, date, Jan 2012)
(JohnJan2012, name, John)
(JohnJan2012, salary, 3244)
```

Does anyone know of a better way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use bNodes here and do, in Turtle syntax, something like:

```
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

:john :salary [
      :amount "3244.0"^^xsd:decimal;
      :date "2012-01-01T00:00:00"^^xsd:datetime;
] .

:john :salary [
      :amount "4012.0"^^xsd:decimal;
      :date "2012-02-01T00:00:00"^^xsd:datetime;
] .
```

Here I am creating two records of those examples you gave. the `[]` syntax creates a blank node that is basically a node without a name (URI). From each of these blank nodes in the example we have two pieces of information date and amount.

Also, make sure you use valid `xsd:datetime` dates if you want to use SPARQL later on to query your data.

Answer (score 6):

## Original 2012 Answer

For a fuller discussion of the different ways you can represent time in RDF see Ian Davis'
s excellent blog post [Representing Time in RDF](https://blog.iandavis.com/2009/08/representing-time-in-rdf-part-1/) series on this topic

---

## 2023 Update

Nowadays 4D Ontologies are gaining a lot of traction as a more formal way to model spatial-temporal relationships within knowledge graphs.

Again Ian Davis' has a new [blog post series](https://telicent.io/news/4d-ontology-pt1-the-why/) (on his corporate blog) that covers these.

**Disclaimer:** As of writing this update in 2023 I work for Ian